# array_udiff on arrays with strings and objects

Tags: php

I want the difference between 2 arrays. These arrays can contain strings or objects. I just want `array_udiff` to check based on the string (if its a string), or object type (if its an object).

Here is what I've tried:

```
$field_rules = ['required', new \App\Rules\MyCustomRule];
$rules_ignore_realtime = ['confirmed', new \App\Rules\MyCustomRule];

$diff_rules = array_udiff($field_rules, $rules_ignore_realtime, function ($a, $b) {
    if (is_object($a)) return $a instanceof $b;
    else return $a == $b;
});
```

This always results in an empty array. I'm also not sure if `instanceof` is what I should be using here.

Comment: [`get_class`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) is probably more appropriate than `instanceof`

Comment: I'm not convinced that `array_udiff()` is necessary / most appropriate.  Please `var_export()` your input data and show us your exact desired output array so that your question and answers are verifiable.  This question is incomplete. @kej

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb:

```
$diff_rules = array_udiff($field_rules, $rules_ignore_realtime, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a != $b;
});
```